# Is there a closed form expression for Landau-level eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Is there a closed form expression for the Landau-level eigenstates (preferably in the symmetric gauge)?  *This is the 2-dimensional quantum mechanical problem of a charged particle moving in a homogenous magnetic field transverse to the plane.*

Because of the similarity to the quantum simple harmonic oscillator, which have closed-form eigenstate expressions in terms of Hermite polynomials, I would have expected something similar to happen for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sure!  The wavefunction, in polar coordinates, for the $N^\text{th}$ Landau level is:

$$\psi(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi N!}}\Big(\frac{eB}{2\hbar}\Big)^{(N+1
)/2} r^N (e^{i\theta})^N \exp\big(-\frac{eB}{4\hbar}r^2\big)$$

Comment: Just to point out that this expression does not specify the dependence on the other quantum number which gives degeneracy.